# Mixed effects model in R with subsampling in replicates

Tags: r, experiment-design, subsampling

I am working on a mixed effects model in r where I have 2 treatments, 5 replications and subsampling with each site. I dont have access to the raw subsampling data though, I just have the mean effect size for each replication, number of subsamples at each replication, and pooled variance at each replication.

I am experimenting with this code. Would this be valid given my experimental design and data limitations?

```r
model <- lmer(EffectSize ~ Treatment + (1 | Replication) + 
                 (1 | Replication:Subsampling), 
              data = data, 
              weights = 1/Variance)
```

Comment: Your model says that `Subsampling` is nested within `Replication`, which I think makes sense from what you said, but that is really a feature of the study design and the data, so you are best placed to determine if that't the case. If it is, then does the model output results that make sense ? Perhaps you can edit the question to show us the output from `summary(model)`?